# Optimise Django query with large subquery

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a database containing `Profile` and `Relationship` models. I haven't explicitly linked them in the models (because they are third party IDs and they may not yet exist in both tables), but the `source` and `target` fields map to one or more `Profile` objects via the `id` field:

```
from django.db import models
class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    handle = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Relationship(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    source = models.BigIntegerField(db_index=True)
    target = models.BigIntegerField(db_index=True)
```

My query needs to get a list of 100 values from the `Relationship.source` column which don't yet exist as a `Profile.id`. This list will then be used to collect the necessary data from the third party. The query below works, but as the table grows (10m+), the SubQuery is getting very large and slow.

Any recommendations for how to optimise this? Backend is PostgreSQL but I'd like to use native Django ORM if possible.

EDIT: There's an extra level of complexity that will be contributing to the slow query. Not all IDs are guaranteed to return success, which would mean they continue to "not exist" and get the program in an infinite loop. So I've added a `filter` and `order_by` to input the highest `id` from the previous batch of 100. This is going to be causing some of the problem so apologies for missing it initially.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery
user = Profile.objects.get(handle="philsheard")
qs_existing_profiles = Profiles.objects.all()
rels = TwitterRelationship.objects.filter(
    target=user.id,
).exclude(
    source__in=Subquery(qs_existing_profiles.values("id"))
).values_list(
    "source", flat=True
).order_by(
    "source"
).filter(
    source__gt=max_id_from_previous_batch  # An integer representing a previous `Relationship.source` id
)
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Well, `IN` query  is not the best choice, especially with 10M+ rows. Try having the source as foreignkey. Or using ANY(...) for faster results.

Comment: Thanks @style. I'm not familiar with `ANY()` in the context of the Django ORM. Could you provide a simple example?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in django ORM.. or whether it is possible, but you can add it as a native query.
Another solution would be to analyze it upon inserting a new relationship and have a boolean field of `related_to_profile` - that way you can query for it instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future searchers, here's how I bypassed the `__in` query and was able to speed up the results.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery
from django.db.models import Count  # New

user = Profile.objects.get(handle="philsheard")
subq = Profile.objects.filter(profile_id=OuterRef("source"))  # New queryset to use within Subquery
rels = Relationship.objects.order_by(
    "source"
).annotate(
    # Annotate each relationship record with a Count of the times that the "source" ID
    # appears in the `Profile` table. We can then filter on those that have a count of 0
    # (ie don't appear and therefore haven't yet been connected)
    prof_count=Count(Subquery(subq.values("id")))
).filter(
    target=user.id,
    prof_count=0
).filter(
    source__gt=max_id_from_previous_batch  # An integer representing a previous `Relationship.source` id
).values_list(
    "source", flat=True
)
```

I think this is faster because the query will complete once it reaches it's required 100 items (rather than comparing against a list of 1m+ IDs each time).